# How to setup queue such a way all subscribers get messages - Rabbit MQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am reading RabbitMQ in Action book, stil in the chapter 2, but one thing authors says puzzling me. You setup a exchange and send a message, two subscribers are listening to the queue. When the first message comes in, the first subscriber gets it and the message is removed once it is acknowledged. When the next messages arrives it goes to the next listener in round robin way. I thought, if I am sending a message, I want all the subscribers to get it. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this, http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is simple. If you want all subscribers to get a copy of the message, then create multiple queues with a wildcard binding.

Assuming that you have a topic exchange, and you publish all messages with a routing key like fred.interesting or fred.boring, then if each subscriber declares a queue with the binding key of fred.*, then each queue will get a copy of every message. The only issue is how to name the queues, although RabbitMQ can generate unique names for you if you wish.

If I were doing this I would have a supervisor process that starts and monitors the message consumer processes. The supervisor would assign each consumer process a queue name like fred0001, fred0002 and keep track of which names are in play. Using specified names like this makes it easier to use management tools or write management and monitoring scripts.

Comment: I would (and indeed do) configure my subscribers such that they are individually responsible for registering their own queues with the appropriate routing keys. Setting them up as self-deleting queues ensures that once the consumer's connection is lost, the queue is torn down too.