# Broadcasting message to all connected users using websocket (Erlang, RabbitMQ, Websocket, Gen_bunny, Cowboy)

Tags: erlang, websocket, rabbitmq, cowboy

I am trying to integrate websocket chat using ERlang, Cowboy, Websocket and gen_bunny.

I am able to get them work independently.

Browser -> Cowboy websocket chat (Works)
Erlang and RabbitMQ AMQP (Works)

When integrating them together i am able to get the message from browser to Cowboy and pass it to RabbitMQ and again get it back from RabbitMQ.

I can even reply the message to the user who sent it. However, I want to broadcast the message to all connected Users.

As per my understanding Erlang will create a separate process for each user. So, how to broadcast it to all connected users after I get back the response from RabbitMQ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on gproc project: https://github.com/uwiger/gproc

It has a  Pub/Sub pattern that you may use to build the chat you mentioned.

From gproc's wiki:

```
subscribe(EventType) ->
    %% Gproc notation: {p, l, Name} means {(p)roperty, (l)ocal, Name}
    gproc:reg({p, l, {?MODULE, EventType}}).

notify(EventType, Msg) -> 
    Key = {?MODULE, EventType},
    gproc:send({p, l, Key}, {self(), Key, Msg}).
```

Comment: Hey Edyardo, Thanks for replt.. However, Before using RabbitMQ i did experiment with Gproc. Problem is there will be many cowboy instances running and from scalability point of view I would like to use a Messaging queue.

Comment: Hmm.. I see. But did you see that gproc supports local and global processes?

Comment: I think I will change the architecture a bit and will use GProc and RabbitMQ in combination...

Answer (score 2):

Correct--Cowboy creates a per-connection process that runs your WebSocket handler code. One approach is to have the handler's `websocket_init/3` function register itself with a "broadcast" process (and unregister in `websocket_terminate/3`). Upon receiving a message from RabbitMQ, the broadcast process repeats the message to all registered WebSocket connections, which can receive it using the `websocket_info/3` handler callback.

The broadcast process can use [monitors](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id83220) to discover when a WebSocket handler dies, and automatically remove it from the registration list.

The life of a handler, then, might look something like this:

1. `websocket_init/3` is called after Cowboy performs the protocol upgrade requested in `init/3` (to WebSocket). From here, the client handler registers itself with `broadcast`, the message broadcasting process.
2. As long as the connection remains open, the handler receives message broadcasts to its `websocket_info/3`, passing messages along to the client by returning `{reply, {text, Message}, State}`.
3. Upon termination, the handler unregisters itself with `broadcast`. If for some reason this doesn't work as intended, `broadcast` keeps monitors on all subscribers so as to get notified of their deaths.

Comment: Thanks Martin, But I want to avoid loops as the number of users and message exchange are going to be high. so Upon receiving the message from RabbitMQ if I run a  loop and send message to all it will be bottle neck in future. Any other framework which can do the task of broadcasting? I have looked at YAWS and Cowboy...

Comment: Message passing in Erlang is extremely fast (and normally asynchronous). Don't assume it's going to be a bottleneck unless you've measured it. At some point, unless you use some kind of complex map-reduce like pattern to parallelize the broadcasting, you will have a loop that sequentially sends messages to subscribers. To my knowledge, there's no silver bullet here.

Comment: Hmmm...I have used Tsung to benchmarking however results were not so promising. Nevertheless, I am thinking to use GProc and RabbitMQ together..

Comment: @MartinTörnwall in your #2, {reply, {text, Message} ... will send across the websocket, NOT the Ref who messaged the websocket handler?

Answer (score 0):

Every cowboy process get its own Rabbit queue. Broadcast would work with wildcard bindings. No explicit loop involved. You could make the subscription optional by not binding accordingly. See: [How to setup queue such a way all subscribers get messages - Rabbit MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155144/how-to-setup-queue-such-a-way-all-subscribers-get-messages-rabbit-mq)